# Learn a fined-grained periodic function from coarse-grained periodic functions

Tags: machine-learning, signal-processing

I'm a Machine Learning practitioner but not a Signal Processing practitioner.

I have data and I assume they generated by an any periodic function (periodic wave), not necessarily sinusoidal. So I have some questions:

1. What is the best way to learn that function from data please?
2. Let us assume my theoretical fined-grained function (and so my observations) depends on piecing of coarse-grained functions a bit like Fourier transform. Does exist a model or algorithms doing that please? A bit like [Benveniste's wavelet network](http://people.rennes.inria.fr/Albert.Benveniste/pub/Wavenets.pdf)

   2.a. Always with the same assumption, if I want to model my fine-grained function with a **known** couple of coarse-grained functions, is there a way (model, algorithm, etc.) to find out the best combination of these coarse-grained functions modeling my fine-grained function.

Feel you free to inform me about fields or papers about that field.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. In the context of Fourier analysis, the fine and coarse scale functions are orthogonal, so you cannot really represent one in terms of the other by superposition. If you are stretching/scaling the functions, then that is more like wavelets. Are you perhaps asking about something more like [super-resolution](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=super+resolution)?

Comment: What do you want to say by telling "fine and coarse scale functions are orthogonal, so you cannot really represent one in terms of the other by superposition" please? I want approximate a periodic function with combination of other more simple periodic functions (sinusoids). In the first case I don't know theses more simple periodic functions and I want the optimal and in the second case I assume a batch of them and I want to find out optimal combination of them. The problem with wavelets is they are not periodic.

Comment: When I talk about optimal combination of known simpler periodic functions I mean getting optimal phase (coefficient of sin) and phase for example. Therein it related to Fourier Transform I guess. The problem with wavelets is they are not periodic.